# How to output coordinates of configurable point on a graph to a table with bokeh

Tags: python, slider, bokeh

## Original Question

I have a graph defined by the function y/100 = (x/100)^n

I want to decide x with a slider on `bokeh` and (i) mark the point with dotted lines on the x- and y-axes, and (ii) find the related y-coordinate on a table below the slider.

Here is what I have tried, but with no success (the slider, table and graph are all there, but nothing happens when the slider is moved).

```
###  Slider:: Interactive Graph with Python Bokeh
###  Source:: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

#%%  Read data from graph

##  Define parameters and function

n = 0.333333333333
w1, h1 = 500, 400
w2, h2 = 200,  80

def x_to_y(x):
    y = 100*((x*0.01)**n)
    y = np.round(y, 2)
    return y


##  Initialize the graph 

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1001)
y = x_to_y(x)

cust_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, step=0.1, 
                     value=30, 
                     width=w2, height=h2,
                     title="% Customers")


##  Create a table with (x, y) values of the graph... 
##              read x from slider

tabl = dict(cust=[cust_slider.value],
            potn=[x_to_y(cust_slider.value)])

values = ColumnDataSource(tabl)

columns = [TableColumn(field="cust", title="% Customers"),
           TableColumn(field="potn", title="% Potential")]

data_table = DataTable(source=values, 
                       columns=columns,
                       width=w2, height=h2, 
                       editable=True)


##  Plot the graph from  function (later to be read from source)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

TOOLTIPS = [("Customers: ", "$x"),
            ("Potential: ", "$y")
           ]

plot = figure(x_range=(0,100),
              y_range=(0, 100), 
              tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
              plot_width=w1, 
              plot_height=h1)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)
plot.line([0,cust_slider.value,cust_slider.value], 
          [x_to_y(cust_slider.value),x_to_y(cust_slider.value),0],
          line_dash="dashed"
         )

plot.add_layout(Title(text="Customers (%)", align="center"), "below")
plot.add_layout(Title(text="Potential (%)", align="center"), "left")


##  Try to make table and plot interactive  (...table not interacting)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=tabl, 
                              slider=cust_slider),
                    code="""const source = source.data;
                            const xx = source['cust'];
                            const yy = source['potn'];
                            xx = slider.value;
                            yy = x_to_y(xx);
                            source.change.emit();"""
                   )

cust_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)


layout = row(plot,
             column(cust_slider,
                    data_table)
            )

output_file("slider_mwe.html", title="Graph")

show(layout)
```

Here is a snapshot of the figure I got:[image]

## Edit: Solution inspired by [bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot)

```
###  Slider:: Interactive Graph with Python Bokeh
###  Source:: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

#%%  Read data from graph

##  Define parameters and function

n = 0.333333333333
w1, h1 = 500, 400
w2, h2 = 200,  80

def x_to_y(x):
    y = 100*((x*0.01)**n)
    y = np.round(y, 2)
    return y


##  Initialize the graph 

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1001)
y = x_to_y(x)

##  ...and the data-point in focus
x0 = np.linspace(30, 30, 1)
y0 = x_to_y(x0)


cust_slider = Slider(start=0, end=100, step=0.1, 
                     value=30, 
                     width=w2, height=h2,
                     title="% Customers")


##  Create a table with (x, y) values of the graph... 
##              read x from slider

tabl = dict(cust=[cust_slider.value],
            potn=[x_to_y(cust_slider.value)])
tlin = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lin_cust=np.insert(x0, 0, [0, x0[0]]),
                                  lin_potn=np.insert(y0, 1, [y0[0], 0])))


values = ColumnDataSource(tabl)

columns = [TableColumn(field="cust", title="% Customers"),
           TableColumn(field="potn", title="% Potential")]

data_table = DataTable(source=values, 
                       columns=columns,
                       width=w2, height=h2, 
                       editable=True)


##  Plot the graph from  function (later to be read from source)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

TOOLTIPS = [("Customers: ", "$x"),
            ("Potential: ", "$y")
           ]

plot = figure(x_range=(0,100),
              y_range=(0, 100), 
              tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
              plot_width=w1, 
              plot_height=h1)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)
plot.line('lin_cust', 'lin_potn', source=tlin, line_dash="dashed")

plot.add_layout(Title(text="Customers (%)", align="center"), "below")
plot.add_layout(Title(text="Potential (%)", align="center"), "left")


##  Plot made interactive  by writing to values & tlin 
##                        (rather than declared constants)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, 
                              values=values, 
                              tlin=tlin, 
                              slider=cust_slider),
                    code="""values.data['cust'][0] = slider.value;
                            for (var i = 0; i < source.data['x'].length; i++) 
                            {   
                                if (source.data['x'][i] == slider.value) 
                                {
                                    values.data['potn'][0] = source.data['y'][i];
                                }
                            }
                            tlin.data['lin_cust'][1] = values.data['cust'][0]
                            tlin.data['lin_cust'][2] = values.data['cust'][0]
                            tlin.data['lin_potn'][0] = values.data['potn'][0]
                            tlin.data['lin_potn'][1] = values.data['potn'][0]
                            values.change.emit();
                            tlin.change.emit();"""
                   )

cust_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)


layout = row(plot,
             column(cust_slider,
                    data_table)
            )

output_file("slider_mwe.html", title="Graph")

show(layout)
```

which gives everything in place:

[image]

...except that at times the corner of the dotted line falls off the curve.

---

Well, I thought it should be given that little freedom for the sake of what it all has done for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues. First, your `CustomJS` code:

```
const source = source.data;
const xx = source['cust'];
const yy = source['potn'];
xx = slider.value;
yy = x_to_y(xx);
source.change.emit();
```

Does not actually do anything that has any effect. When you create local variables `xx` and `yy` and then re-assign values to them, that only affects the local variables ,and nothing else. In particular, nothing about the Bokeh data source was changed (so nothing about the plot will change).

Additionally, the values in a `ColumnDataSource` must be actual columns (i.e. lists or arrays) not single numbers as you are assigning above.

You probably intend something more like:

```
source.data['cust'] = [0, slider.value, slider.value]
```

which actually modifies the contents of `source.data`.

However, you also have one other issue, which is that for the other column, you are trying to call the *Python function* `x_to_y` in your `CustomJS` callback code. This can never work. `CustomJS` callback code is executed *in the browser*, and browsers only know how to execute JavaScript code. You will have to perform that conversion with JS code in the callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I edited my question to give the solution in line with your tips and tricks.  They worked wonderfully !

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works! An "accept" on the answer would be appreciated (better for the project to have as few "unanswered" questions here a possible)